# onsen with jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

I ran into an issue where I couldn't select an element using jquery within onsen framework. I couldn't figure out why. So any onsen experts out there could help me?

The below code could be seen live at 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/fctbd'

My 2nd alert always gives me 0 while the 1st one says found 1.  Then I have an onClick function on the button when I click it, I could access the button. I'm confused. Maybe there's something else I could detect.. maybe pageinit doesn't finish rendering the bottom toolbar?

Any ideas?

**JS**

```
ons.bootstrap();

$(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("document READY");
  $(document.body).on("pageinit","#mainPage", function() {
    console.log("page init") ;    
    alert($("ons-button#power-btn").length);
    alert($("#power-button").length);
  });
});

function onOff() {
  alert($("#power-button").length);
}
```

**html**

```
    <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-page id="mainPage">
    <p id="para1">Hello there</p>

        <ons-bottom-toolbar>
        <div class="center" style="background-color: #D5DBD7">
                <ons-row>
                <ons-col>
                  <div id="my-div"></div>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-step-backward" style="font-size:30px"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-play" style="font-size:30px" id="play-button"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-step-forward" style="font-size:30px"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet" onClick="switchAudio()">
                    <div class="fa fa-microphone" style="font-size:30px" id="mic-button"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:30px"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:30px"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet">
                    <div class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:30px;" id="setup-button"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                <ons-button class="toolbar-button--quiet" id="power-btn" onclick="onOff()">
                    <div class="fa fa-power-off" style="font-size:30px;" id="power-button"></div>
                </ons-button>
                </ons-col>
                </ons-row>
            </div>
        </ons-botom-toolbar>
     </ons-page>
   </ons-navigator>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question! :) After hours of trying, I found an answer which was one of the things I tried before but at the time for some reason, it didn't work (maybe cached issue?). What I did was, accessing the field within ons.ready block, instead of document.ready block.

Comment: Why do you use page init event?

$(document.body).on("pageinit","#mainPage", function() {
    //do something
});

I think it causes the problem. If I removed the line, it worked well

Comment: Ah!!!! Thank you! There was no reason :) It was just a part of trials and errors... as I'm still learning along!

Comment: @VuNguyen: Can you please look into this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377268/how-to-retain-json-objects-in-multiple-ons-template-pages-in-onsenui