# How to retain json objects in multiple ons-template pages in onsenui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, onsen-ui

Here I am populating json objects in ajax. In navigator page, it retains all the json objects. But when I switch to another template (page2.html), it doesn't retain the json objects.
I need to populate the userid, acc_nbr(mentioned in the code) in other ons-template pages.

Any help regarding this?
Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "Controller?token=123",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
          $('#userid').html(data.userid);     
          $('#acc_nbr').html(data.accountnbr);      
          },
          error:function(){
            alert("Sorry!");
          }
        });

});
</script>
```

index.html

```
    <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="app.navi">
    <ons-page>
    /*/ content /*/
     <div id="userid"></div>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>

    <ons-template id="page2.html">
    <ons-page>
    /*/ content /*/
    <div id="acc_nbr"></div>
    </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

Comment: for example, I have said like userid. For populating multiple elements it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `<script>` section

```
$(document.body).on("pageinit","#page2.html", function() {
   // call that same ajax function
}
```